Convert cathedral ceiling in bathroom to storage space
I have a bathroom with cathedral ceilings and do not like it.  I want to add a rim joist around the room and create a flat ceiling.  I have a solid plan on doing that.  However, I now have this space above the bathroom.  If I seal it off, it becomes unconditioned and I know I'd need to do something.  Can't just seal it up.  If I make it conditioned storage, can I just have a pass through ducting system to allow air to get into/out of the space or does it need to have ducting added?  Doesn't seem like I'd want the pass through duct to be in the bathroom?  Too much damp air flowing up there.  Thanks for your "constructive" thoughts!  ;-)

Some photos would sure help your cause here.

Don't have pics to help here.  Picture a bathroom with a cathedral ceiling.  Now put a flat ceiling in and imagine that cathedral ceiling being cut off.  Really an HVAC question here I think on how to most efficiently and economically keep the space conditioned.

So add a couple of return grilles to the new ceiling.
